# Why is binary search faster than ternary search?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, search-algorithms, binary-search

Searching an array of $N$ elements using binary search takes, in the worst case $\log_2 N$ iterations because, at each step we trim half of our search space. 
If, instead, we used 'ternary search', we'd cut away two-thirds of our search space at each iteration, so the worst case should take $\log_3 N < \log_2 N$ iterations...

It seems that ternary search is faster, so why do we use binary search?

Comment: Couldn't one use the same reasoning about Quaternary search? Or even decimal search... or anything larger than 2.

Comment: @d'alar'cop Then Linear Search should be Faster than Binary Search

Comment: That's the difference between a fixed constant and a parameter that grows with $n$.

Comment: please read about B+Trees

Comment: Linear search often is faster than binary search on small-to-medium-sized problems on modern hardware, because it's cache-coherent and almost all branches are predicted correctly.

Comment: @arunmoezhi Could you suggest some good resource for BTrees ??

Comment: If you have an array of n-elements, think about how long an n-ary search would be.

Comment: Also 2*log_3(N) = log_3(N^2) if it speaks to your intuition.

Comment: Let's put this into intuitive terms. If using a 3-based search is faster because it cuts the search space more at each iteration, then isn't using a million-based search faster? But you can easily see that on average you'd have to do 500,000 checks inside each iteration to determine the 1-millionth slice that contained the target. Clearly, cutting the search space in half each iteration and no more, gives you the *most* information in a single step, reliably.

Comment: any standard textbook for databases would discuss BTrees. Fundamentals of database systems" by Ramez Elmasri. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree

Comment: @ErikE A mathematical expression is better than thousands of words..

Comment: @DigitalBrain That depends on your purpose and your audience, doesn't it? The ability to explain mathematical concepts in everyday terms isn't one that all people possess, but it's an important ability given the fact that the ability to understand all pure mathematical expressions  isn't one that all people possess--and what are they to do if no one who can understand the form can translate them to the latter?

Comment: @ErikE, but isn't the time complexity "lower" for higher $k$ for a $k$-ary search? End of page 1 in [this](https://iiitdm.ac.in/old/Faculty_Teaching/Sadagopan/pdf/DAA/new/recurrence-relations-V3.pdf). $T(n) = \theta(\log_k n)$. Or am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: @sprajagopal how many steps does each increment in k add?

Comment: Several times I read “if ternary search were faster, then n-ary search should be even faster and it isn’t”. That’s a non-sequitur. N-ary search for some n is optimal. It’s not at all obvious whether this happens for n=2 or n=3 or n=4. It turns out 3-ary search uses a lot more comparisons but only if you blunder in the implementation. The accepted answer makes that mistake. With a correct implementation things are very close.

Comment: I understand about 50% of this. Kinda surprised about how subjective this is. Looks like _it depends_ on a lot of things.
@ErikE, what do you mean y "steps?" My understanding is that ternary search is worse because it eliminates less search space every step.

Comment: @sprajagopal any algorithm must be implemented in code. And at the end of the day, the cost of that algorithm is realized in CPU instructions and the time it takes to execute them. We tend to use higher level concepts such as “steps” to stand in for small clusters of instructions that perform a discrete task and this usually has validity. One expression evaluation or one control flow statement can be called a step. How many steps are needed to do _n_-ary search? Well, implement a few and count.

Comment: @sprajagopal If there were some way to learn in only a single step which bucket of three the desired target lay within, then 3-way search would be faster. But that is almost never the case. Usually, determining which bucket of three will take more than one comparison. On average, it will take 5/3 comparisons (1 x 1/3 + 2 * 2/3) to cut the search space into 1/3. Since 1/3 is 2/3 of 1/2, binary search has to beat 5/3 * 2/3 average comparisons, and it does, taking only 1 instead of 10/9.

Comment: @sprajagopal parallelism is one case that can make higher n be more efficient in time, but this is just parallelization, which is not really valid for Big O algorithmic complexity assessment.

Comment: @gnasher729 “very close” as in, 10/9 is more than 1? With non-blundered implementations. It actually seems obvious to me that binary search is fastest. See my previous comments for why.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you apply binary search, you have $$\log_2(n)+O(1)$$ many comparisons. If you apply ternary search, you have $$ 2 \cdot \log_3(n) + O(1)$$ many comparisons, as in each step, you need to perform 2 comparisons to cut the search space into three parts. Now if you do the math, you can observe that:
 $$ 2 \cdot \log_3(n) + O(1) = 2 \cdot \frac{\log(2)}{\log(3)} \log_2(n)+ O(1) $$ Since we know that $2 \cdot \frac{\log(2)}{\log(3)} > 1$, we actually get *more* comparisons with ternary search.

By the way: $n$-ary search may make a lot of sense in case if comparisons are quite costly and can be parallelized, as then, parallel computers can be applied.

Note that argument can be generalized to $n$-ary search quite easily. You just need to show that the function $f(k) = (k-1) \cdot \frac{\log(2)}{\log(k)}$ is strictly monotone increasing for integer values of $k$.

Comment: And LHS is linear & RHS is logarithmic so it won't help for any quaternary or something more than that .... Nice Explanations.... Thanks

Comment: @DigitalBrain Exactly. I just edited the answer to generalize by what you wrote.

Comment: I could've upvoted you for that .... But no way to do that .. Thanks again

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: note that an abstract measure like the number of element comparisons may or may not dominate actual runtime. In particular, you might have to consider how many cache misses you are likely to get on long arrays with either search. (Here, they coincide. I'm just noting this because the OP asks, "why is it faster?", and answering that with an abstract measure can be misleading for some algorithms.)

Comment: *"you need to perform 2 comparison to cut the search space into three parts"* Hits the nail on the head.  If we used ternary computing devices, ternary would be one comparison per search space division, but since we use binary computers, then a binary search space will be more efficient than a ternary search space.

Comment: In a ternary search, 1/3 of the time you will only need 1 comparison (do lower comparison: if in the lower third, you don't need the second comparison).  That makes ternary only about 5% slower instead of 25% (in this world in which we only care about comparison count).  I'm not sure how to generalize this to n-ary, although I suspect it never gets faster than binary.

Comment: @AaronDufour: Since one could do a quaternary search by comparing to the middle item first and then ignoring the result of the other comparisons, the only way quaternary search could be faster would be if three comparisons could be done in parallel more cheaply than two comparisons could be performed sequentially.

Comment: @AaronDufour But you are amortizing over elements to search for, and it is not clear to me why that is ok. In the worst case both comparisons may be performed at every step.

Comment: @SashoNikolov I'm not sure why worst case is more important than average.  Its already clear that they only differ by constant multipliers.

Comment: @supercat +1 And then n-ary, completely parallelized, would theoretically be the fastest.

Comment: If we talk about simple time complexity, then the time complexity for a $k$-ary search is $\theta(\log_k n)$ (a [source](https://iiitdm.ac.in/old/Faculty_Teaching/Sadagopan/pdf/DAA/new/recurrence-relations-V3.pdf)). So _theoretically_ higher $k$ is better?

Comment: @sprajagopal No, $k$-ary search is not better in Big-O-notation because $\Theta(\log_k n)$ is exactly the same for every possible value of $k$. This is because $\Theta(\log_k n) = \Theta(\log k \cdot \log n)$ and the $\log k$ is a constant that can be removed in Big-O-notation.

Answer (score 32):

DCTLib is right, but forget the math for a second.

By your logic then, ***n***-ary should be the fastest. But if you think about it, ***n***-ary is exactly equal to a regular iteration search (just iterating through the list 1 by 1, but in reverse order). First you select the last (or next to last) item in the list and compare that value to your comparison value. Then you remove that item from your list, and then choose the last item in the new list, which is just the next to last value in the array. Each time, you would only be eliminating 1 value at a time until you found your value.

Instead, you should think about it like this - how do I eliminate the most values from the list each iteration? In a binary search, you always eliminate half the list. In a ternary search, there is a possibility (33.33% chance, actually) that you can eliminate 2/3 of the list, but there is an even greater chance (66.66%) that you will only eliminate 1/3 of the list. in order to calculate O(n), you need to look at the worst case scenario, which is 1/3, less than 1/2. As you get closer and closer to n, it gets even worse.

Not only will the worst case scenario be improved with binary search, but your *average* time will be improved as well. Looking at expected value (what portion of the list can we remove on average), we use this formula:

$(P_{lower}) \times \text{(portion we can remove if lower)} +(P_{higher}) \times \text{(portion we can remove if higher)} = E$

For binary search, this is $0.5 \times 0.5 + 0.5 \times 0.5 = 0.5$ (we always remove half the list). For ternary searches, this value is $0.666 \times 0.333 + 0.333 \times 0.666 = 0.44$, or at each step, we will likely only remove 44% of the list, making it less efficient than the binary search, on average. This value peaks at $1/2$ (half the list), and decreases the closer you get to n (reverse iteration) and $0$ (regular iteration).

Ok, so I lied..there's a little math involved, but I hope that helps!

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: Ya boundary analysis helps understand hard math ! n-ary sequential search has the same cost of linear search O(n) .

Answer (score -2):

Please note the log(N) vs 2 log(N) comparisons argument is based on a naive interpretation of the algorithm. If I were to actually sit down and write this in x86 assembly the results would be inverted. The problem is the use of integers for test cases combined with an insufficiently smart compiler that can't remove the redundant comparisons. Retry with strings and an appropriate string comparison function, and code it to call the comparison function once per loop and you will find the ternary search is faster again.

Comment: Of course ternary search would be faster if you could do it with only one comparison per iteration. But, no matter if strings or integers, you can't.

Comment: The comparisons would not be redundant and the problem has nothing to do with the compiler. In order to divide the search space into three parts, you need 2 comparisons. In a binary search, you need only compare to the middle element and you then know which half of the search space the result would lie in. With ternary search, you'd need to compare with the element 1/3 of the way through the list AND the one 2/3 of the way through the list. What type of data you're comparing or what language you're using is irrelevant. Granted, if the item is in the 1st 3rd, you could stop after 1 comparison.

Comment: On some platforms, ternary search could be faster due to allowing the CPU more time to fetch the operands from RAM before needing them for comparison. But that depends totally on the platform used and its latencies and caches.

Comment: Darn it -- wrong definition of ternary search.